# @EmbeddedId : is not mapped as an embeddable

Tags: eclipse, jpa

I got an Eclipse error with : `@EmbeddedId`.

This is the entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonPK PersonPK;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private int age;
}
```

And the embeddable class :

```
@Embeddable
public class PersonPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;

    public PersonPK() {
    }
}
```

Eclipse show me this error : `PersonPK is not mapped as an embeddable`

Can you tell me why and how to fix that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old question, I know, but having had--and solved--this very problem this morning, here's another possibility:

In your persistence.xml file, if `exclude-unlisted-classes` is set to `true`, then you need to have the `@Embeddable` class listed as a managed class in the persistence unit. So in the above case, you would do something like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">
    <!-- ..... -->
    <class>com.example.foobar.Person</class>
    <class>com.example.foobar.PersonPK</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <!-- ..... -->
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: was exactly my problem.... thx! I´m wondering why my application worked on glassfish...

Answer (score 1):

You could also disable JPA validation for builds.

Right-click on the project and select properties. Select Validation and check Enable project specific settings. Uncheck JPA Validator. Clean the project.

Source: [Problem with JPA Project in Eclipse - error in class annotated @Entity: Table "xxx" cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475228/problem-with-jpa-project-in-eclipse-error-in-class-annotated-entity-table-x)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible `PersonPK` is listed as an `Entity` in an `orm.xml` file. The settings in an `orm.xml` file override the Java annotations. Remove `PersonPK` from the `orm.xml` file (or list it as an `Embeddable` there also) and the error will go away.

Comment: I don't have PersonPK listed in my orm.xml. How to list it as Embeddable ?

Comment: If you do not already have an `orm.xml` file, you probably do not need to create one. But, if you do not have an `orm.xml` file, I do not know what could be causing that particular error. What version of Eclipse are you using? Does it have any third party extensions added to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your `orm.xml`

```
<entity-mappings> 
<entity class="package.Person"> 
<attributes> 
... 
<embedded-id name="personPK"/> 
... 
</attributes> 
</entity> 
<embeddable class="package.PersonPK"/> 
</entity-mappings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

In my case I had an @Entity annotation on PersonPK (the Embeddable class).

Don't combine @Entity and @Embeddable on the same class :)

I removed @Entity from PersonPK and all is now good with the world.