# How to auto detect entities in JPA 2.0

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am pretty sure that I used some sort of auto detection of beans annotated with @Entity in JPA 2.0 in the past but I am not able to find out how. How do you do that instead of listing each bean in a `class` XML element in the persistence.xml?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Spring 3.1, you also have the option to [forget persistence.xml](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#new-in-3.1-jpa-without-xml) altogether, and configure your `EntityManagerFactory` using the `packagesToScan` property, similar to this:

```xml
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:packagesToScan="${jpa.entity.packages}">

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
              p:showSql="${hibernate.show_sql}"/>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I know that, but I asked about JPA persistence.xml

Comment: I know, just wanted to mention this option as well, because it's a nice way to solve the problem at hand (autodetecting entity classes).

Answer (score 25):

You need add to the `persistence.xml` the next line:

```xml
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

e.g.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" ...>
    <persistence-unit name="YourPU" ...>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" 
                value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

See Pascal Thivent answer here : [Do I need <class> elements in persistence.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780341/do-i-need-class-elements-in-persistence-xml)

you have different way to do it, but JPA itself does not support auto-scan. The simplest and cleanest way to reference your entities IMHO is to package your model in a jar and to reference it with `<jar-file>MyModel.jar</jar-file>`