# eclipse link without any class or mapping file

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

as you can see in this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html when you declare an entity like Person then you must add it in persistence.xml  likes `<class>de.vogella.jpa.eclipselink.model.Person</class>` or you can define a mapping file and put your classes in there, but when you use hibernate as you can see here http://www.alexecollins.com/tutorial-hibernate-jpa-part-1/ after entity declaration you don't need to add anything in persistence.xml as class. or maybe I misundrestood.

I want eclipe link does the same way that hibernate does, means I should use eclipse link and I don,t want to declare class or use any mapping file, does it possible or it doesn't?

thanks

Comment: Did you check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/16088219/496099 ?

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to ignore `<class>` annotation from persistence.xml & you wanted your eclipse to auto detect annotated class files right? Then try the following,

Right click on the project, click Properties, select JPA, in the **Persistence class management** select **Discover annotated classes automatically**.

[image]

Referred link: [Do I need <class> elements in persistence.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780341/do-i-need-class-elements-in-persistence-xml)