# No Qualifying Bean of type found for dependency for @Autowired service

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on my first Spring Boot application from scratch and have been mimicking the style of other examples found online etc. I have the following directory structure:

```
|com.riisan.core
|\
||config
||\
|||RiisanConfig
|||JerseyConfig
||domain
||\
|||Game
|||Player
||repository
||\
|||GameRespository
||resources
||\
|||Games
||service
||\
|||impl
|||\ 
||||GameServiceImpl
|||GameService
```

Within the main config file, I have:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class RiisanConfig {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SpringApplication.run(RiisanConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

I've marked both Game and Player with `@Entity`, and the repository looks like:

```
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends JpaRepository<Game, String> {
    List<Game> findAll();
}
```

My resource component is:

```
@Component
@Path("/games")
@Api(value = "/games", description = "Games REST")
public class Games {
    @Autowired
    GameService gameService;

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get all Games", response = Game.class, responseContainer = "List")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Game> getAllGames(){
        return gameService.getAllGames();
    }
}
```

And finally, the service and service implementation are as follows:

```
public interface GameService {
    public List<Game> getAllGames();

    public Game saveGame(Game game);
}

@Service
public class GameServiceImpl implements GameService {
    @Autowired
    GameRepository gameRepository;

    public List<Game> getAllGames() {
        return gameRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Game saveGame(Game game) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Everything works up to creating the `GET` request. Upon receiving the GET request, I receive an error:

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.riisan.core.service.GameService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

I've tried all the steps in other SE posts, such as changing `@Service` to `@Service("gameService")` or adding `@Qualifier`, but to no avail. This structure and all the annotations mirror that of a working application I used as a base for trying to set up this application, with the slight tweak that the working application is using a MongoRepository instead of JpaRepository. What is causing this error?

UPDATE:
Attempting some of the answers below, I tried:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.riisan.core")
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class RiisanConfig {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SpringApplication.run(RiisanConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

This results in the following errors upon launching the application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'games': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.riisan.core.service.GameService com.riisan.core.resources.Games.gameService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gameServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.riisan.core.repository.GameRepository com.riisan.core.service.impl.GameServiceImpl.gameRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.riisan.core.repository.GameRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at ... ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.riisan.core.service.GameService com.riisan.core.resources.Games.gameService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gameServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.riisan.core.repository.GameRepository com.riisan.core.service.impl.GameServiceImpl.gameRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.riisan.core.repository.GameRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at ... ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gameServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.riisan.core.repository.GameRepository com.riisan.core.service.impl.GameServiceImpl.gameRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.riisan.core.repository.GameRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at ... ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.riisan.core.repository.GameRepository com.riisan.core.service.impl.GameServiceImpl.gameRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.riisan.core.repository.GameRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at ... ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.riisan.core.repository.GameRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I additionally tried listing the package for the repository in `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.riisan.core.repsitory"), which leads to [Not an managed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664064/spring-boot-not-an-managed-type). I tried copying the answer listed there, but the directory structure is different which is probably causing the problem.

Comment: Might be that you need to annotate `GameServiceImpl` with `@Component`.

Comment: Move your `Games` class to `com.riisan.core` remove all the annotations but `@SpringBootApplication`... Then restart your application. Now everything will be detected and picked up automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `@ComponentScan` without a specifying a base package, from the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html):

> If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur **from the package of the class that declares this annotation.**

(emphasis is mine)

---

Note, the same goes for: [`@EnableJpaRepositories`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html)

Comment: When I add the `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.riisan.core"})`, or list any number of the packages, including all of them, all the autowires fail.

Comment: Edit your question, and post the stacktrace you get when "all the autowires fail"

Comment: Turns out I also needed `@EntityScan` to avoid the `Not an managed type` problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try `@ComponentScan("com.riisan.core.service.impl")` in `RiisanConfig`. Spring by default scans sub-packages, but com.riisan.core.service.impl is not a subpackage of com.riisan.core.config

Also, `List<Game> findAll()`; in `GameRepository`  is unnecessary, as `CrudRepository` (a super-interface of `JpaRepository`) already includes a `findAll()`. (`JpaRepository` additionally adds a `findAll` that takes a Paging argument.)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all annotations from RiisanConfig but @SpringBootApplication.