# org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan on Spring Boot 1.5.0-snapshot

Tags: spring-boot

The EntityScan class has removed from SpringBoot 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT,
When i change to 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT version, EntityScan exist.

i must add another dependancy to use EntityScan with SpringBoot 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT ?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8231

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read the release notes:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#entityscan :

> The `@org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan` annotation has been
>   deprecated and should be replaced with
>   `@org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan` or
>   explicit configuration.

Comment: In the future, please make your answer more self-contained. I have added what I think is the most relevant quote, but you really shouldn't only rely on links only.