# Spring boot (2.0.4.RELEASE) - IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with spring boot application trying to connect with manual datasource , when run project i get exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accountService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accountDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.springstudy.demo.model.Account
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.springstudy.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accountDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.springstudy.demo.model.Account
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.springstudy.demo.model.Account
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.springstudy.demo.model.Account
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:73) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:180) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:118) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:298) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
```

Following are the classes used in my application

DemoApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.springstudy.demo")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Database Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MYSQLConfig {

  // ------------------------
  // PUBLIC METHODS
  // ------------------------

  /**
   * DataSource definition for database connection. Settings are read from
   * the application.properties file (using the env object).
   */
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
    return dataSource;
  }

  /**
   * Declare the JPA entity manager factory.
   */
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory =
        new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

    // Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
        env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

    // Vendor adapter
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    // Hibernate properties
    Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.dialect", 
        env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.show_sql", 
        env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", 
        env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

    return entityManagerFactory;
  }

  /**
   * Declare the transaction manager.
   */
  @Bean
  public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
        entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

  /**
   * PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor is a bean post processor
   * which adds an advisor to any bean annotated with Repository so that any
   * platform-specific exceptions are caught and then rethrown as one
   * Spring's unchecked data access exceptions (i.e. a subclass of 
   * DataAccessException).
   */
  @Bean
  public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
  }


  // ------------------------
  // PRIVATE FIELDS
  // ------------------------

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;


}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface AccountDao extends JpaRepository<Account, Long>{

}
```

Model (entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_account")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name ="id_user")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "usrname")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name ="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "modifiedDate")
    private Date modifiedDate;
```

Service

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {
    @Autowired
   AccountDao accountDao;
    @Transactional
    public Account save(Account account) {
        return account;

    }
}
```

This is my project structure : 
[image]

I spent a lot of time and tried to figure out what I am doing wrong... No Idea.
I tried to add `@ComponentScan("com.springstudy.demo")`, `@EntityScan("com.springstudy.demo")` and other solutions from stack but
getting the same error.

Comment: check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664064/spring-boot-not-an-managed-type)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add following annotation to your configuration class:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"<package-name>"})
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually you made things more complicated as you want to explicitly define the JPA configuration in the `MYSQLConfig` bean.
It means that you will not use any longer [the whole auto configuration provided by  Spring Boot for the JPA concern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-jpa-and-spring-data).
For information, actually what you set can be valued by an `application.properties/yml` that will add required properties in the Spring environment.
For example :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mydb
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
...
```

---

Concerning, your problem it is probably here :

```
entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(           
      env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));
```

This property doesn't seem to exist in Spring Boot 2.
You can make your configuration more robust by invoking `getRequiredProperty()` instead of `getProperty()` such as :

```
entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(           
      env.getRequiredProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));
```

If you really need to set `entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan()` programmatically, you could set this value as :

```
entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(DemoApplication.getPackage().toString());
```

as `DemoApplication` is located in the root package of any candidate beans of your application.
Or you could also rely on the package of any entity class if all entities are in the same base package such as :

```
entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(Account.getPackage().toString());
```

It is better than hardcoded the `com.springstudy.demo.model` package that could change in the future :

```
entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.springstudy.demo.model");
```

Comment: thanks for your replay @davidxxx.Its relay help full.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Spring Boot 2.1.5. The problem was that i used a JDBC driver of Pervasive Database.

So, i have to include Spring Data JDBC Support in my build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
```

and that solve my problem.