# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages

Tags: spring-boot, spring-statemachine

in a java springboot application (java 11 and springboot 2.6.15)

after removing maven dependency: spring-statemachine-cosmos-spring-boot-starter version 3.7.0

I got this error when I try to start springboot application:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base package

I removed all junit tests in the application but the problem is still there

can you give me an advice?

Regards

> I expecting to run the application without this error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages

new updates 19/12/2023:

maven tree part of result

> [INFO] com.wba:prt-mgr:jar:9.10-SNAPSHOT [INFO] +-
> com.pltfrmx:tracing-spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.0:compile [INFO] |  +-
> **org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure**:jar:2.6.15:compile
> [INFO] |  - com.pltfrmx:tracing:jar:1.2.0:compile [INFO] |     +-
> org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.27:compile [INFO] |     -
> io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.13.9:compile [INFO] |        -
> io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave:jar:2.16.3:compile
>
> +- com.pltfrmx:tracing-spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.0:compile [INFO] |
> +- **org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure**:jar:2.6.15:compile
> [INFO] |  - com.pltfrmx:tracing:jar:1.2.0:compile [INFO] |     +-
> org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.27:compile [INFO] |     -
> io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.13.9:compile [INFO] |        -
> io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave:jar:2.16.3:compile

Comment: Hello! Can you verify if you have org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure dependency in your project? You can run mvn clean dependency:tree.

Comment: yes there are at least one org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure in my project, I updated the post with maven tree result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot 2.1.1 : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages error when running unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087741/spring-boot-2-1-1-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-retrieve-enablea)