# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to create JPA repository with Driver class, but getting "Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type" Please find below code.

```
package org.codejudge.sb.config;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf, DataSource dataSource){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin");
        return  dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
//        em.setPersistenceUnitName("org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider");
        em.setPackagesToScan("data");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        //adapter.setDatabase();
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        return adapter;
    }

}
package org.codejudge.sb.model;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamicUpdate
//@Table(name = "driver")
@Entity
public class Driver {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String email;

  @Digits(integer = 10, fraction = 2)
  @Column(name = "phone_number", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Integer phoneNumber;

  @Column(name = "license_number", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String licenseNumber;

  @Column(name = "car_number", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String carNumber;

}

package org.codejudge.sb.repository;

import org.codejudge.sb.model.Driver;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface DriverRepo extends JpaRepository<Driver, Integer> {
}


package org.codejudge.sb;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.codejudge.sb", "org.codejudge.sb.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"org.codejudge.sb.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"org.codejudge.sb.model"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Slf4j
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Starting Application...");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**ERROR LOG TRACE**

```
 2021-01-21 19:12:11.103  INFO 54796 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2021-01-21 19:12:11.323  WARN 54796 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.codejudge.sb.model.Driver
    2021-01-21 19:12:11.324  INFO 54796 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2021-01-21 19:12:11.324  INFO 54796 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
    2021-01-21 19:12:11.330  INFO 54796 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2021-01-21 19:12:11.345  INFO 54796 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
    
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2021-01-21 19:12:11.352 ERROR 54796 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'driverRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.codejudge.sb.model.Driver
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:826) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
            at org.codejudge.sb.Application.main(Application.java:21) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47) ~[spring-boot-in-docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86) ~[spring-boot-in-docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-in-docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[spring-boot-in-docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.codejudge.sb.model.Driver
            at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:552) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot - Not a managed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664064/spring-boot-not-a-managed-type)

Comment: I tried by changing entity manager "setPackagesToScan" to my entities packages  got below error.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/codejudge/sb/config/WebConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution