# Spring boot IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type

Tags: spring, maven, kotlin

I get this error on the startup. It seems as if it doesnt use the `@EntityScan` at all

My Code is from [Spring JPA](https://kotlination.com/kotlin-spring-jpa-postgresql-spring-boot-example/) but just using this example doesn't work for me since i get this error

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository' defined in com.kotlination.repo.CustomerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on KotlinSpringJpaPostgresqlApplication: Not a managed type: class com.kotlination.model.Customer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at com.kotlination.main.KotlinSpringJpaPostgresqlApplicationKt.main(KotlinSpringJpaPostgresqlApplication.kt:20) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.kotlination.model.Customer
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I have a Controller in `com.kotlination.controller`
main in `com.kotlination.main`
model in `com.kotlination.model`
and repo in `com.kotlination.repo`

Currently my main class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.kotlination"])
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.kotlination.repo")
@EntityScan(basePackages = ["com.kotlination.model"])
class KotlinSpringJpaPostgresqlApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<KotlinSpringJpaPostgresqlApplication>(*args)
}
```

I hope somebody can help me figure out the issue

I also am aware that there are already quite a few similar questions, yet none of those helped me in this case [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664064/spring-boot-not-a-managed-type)

I have tried it without `@EntityScan`, with `@EntityScan`

As per request from devskillup
Spring Boot version is 3.0.0 and the imports:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kotlination</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jpa-postgresql-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>KotlinSpringJpaPostgresql</name>
    <description>KotlinSpringJpaPostgresql</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.7.21</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I was able to fix the issue but i dont know the cause of the error...
Instead of customer i just copied it and renamed it to a different Jar

When i use the Repository with Jar it works, with Customer if creates the error

Is Customer a protected word or something?

Just in case code of the 2 models:

```
package com.kotlination.model

import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
class Customer(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    val id: Long = -1

    constructor() : this("", "")
}
```

```
package com.kotlination.model

import jakarta.persistence.Entity
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue
import jakarta.persistence.Id

@Entity
class Jar(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    val id: Long = -1

    constructor() : this("", "")
}
```

Comment: You can put your import packages section and the version of Spring boot Please.

Comment: I have updated the issue with the imports and Spring boot version at the end

Comment: The easiest solution is to rename the main package **com.kotlination.main** to **com.kotlination** .

Comment: The result is still the same error

Comment: You can and the structure of your project after modification , and test after comment the three annotations : **@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.kotlination"])
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.kotlination.repo")
@EntityScan(basePackages = ["com.kotlination.model"])**

Comment: I have tested it after renaming the package with the 3 annotations: error occurred.  Without the annotations, same thing happened. Renaming the package only made the annotations EnableJpaRepositories and ComponentScan redundant, but there is no change in the error.

Comment: You can put your pom.xml please ?

Comment: I have added my pom at the end

Comment: I have added some additional information, it is fixed but i am uncertain as to why. Once that is cleared up i will mark this question as resolved