# Error trying to inject the repository dependency "required a bean of type"

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-05T06:20:40.567+02:00 ERROR 38404 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'roleRepository': Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository' defined in com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.repository.RoleRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on GestionUsuariosApplication: Not a managed type: class com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.entity.Role
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.GestionUsuariosApplication.main(GestionUsuariosApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository' defined in com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.repository.RoleRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on GestionUsuariosApplication: Not a managed type: class com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.entity.Role
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.entity.Role
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

I have a problem and I don't know what to do and I'm getting completely desperate because I've tried to see all the stackoverflow guides and I can't find the solution

I have this entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "role_permissions")
    @Column(name = "permission")
    private Set<Permission> permissions;

    // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

and this repository

```
@Repository
    public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    
        Optional<Role> findByName(String name);
    
        boolean existsByName(String name);
    
        boolean existsByIdAndUsersIsEmpty(Long id);
    
        void deleteByIdAndUsersIsEmpty(Long id);
    
        boolean existsByIdAndPermissionsContains(Long id, Permission permission);
    
        boolean existsByIdAndUsers_Id(Long roleId, Long userId);
    
        boolean existsByNameAndIdNot(String name, Long id);
        
        @Query("SELECT r FROM Role r JOIN r.users u WHERE u.id = :userId")
        List<Role> findAllByUsers_Id(@Param("userId") Long userId);
    }
```

and i have this service implementation

```
@Service
public class RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService {

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Optional<Role> findById(Long id) {
        return roleRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Role> findByName(String name) {
        return roleRepository.findByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Role> findAllByUserId(Long userId) {
        return roleRepository.findAllByUsers_Id(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public void addUserRole(Long userId, Long roleId) throws UserNotFoundException, RoleNotFoundException {
        // Get the user by ID
        User user = null;
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(userId);
        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            user = optionalUser.get();
        } else {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User with ID " + userId + " not found");
        }

        // Get the role by ID
        Role role = null;
        Optional<Role> optionalRole = roleRepository.findById(roleId);
        if (optionalRole.isPresent()) {
            role = optionalRole.get();
        } else {
            throw new RoleNotFoundException("Role with ID " + roleId + " not found");
        }

        // Add the role to the user's roles and save the user
        Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
        roles.add(role);
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUserRole(Long userId, Long roleId) {
        // Find user by ID
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(userId);
        if (!optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User with ID " + userId + " not found");
        }
        User user = optionalUser.get();

        // Find role by ID
        Optional<Role> optionalRole = roleRepository.findById(roleId);
        if (!optionalRole.isPresent()) {
            throw new RoleNotFoundException("Role with ID " + roleId + " not found");
        }
        Role role = optionalRole.get();

        // Remove role from user's roles
        Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
        if (roles.contains(role)) {
            roles.remove(role);
        } else {
            throw new RoleNotFoundException("User with ID " + userId + " does not have role with ID " + roleId);
        }

        // Save updated user to database
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasRole(Long userId, String roleName) {
        // Find user by ID
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(userId);
        if (!optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User with ID " + userId + " not found");
        }
        User user = optionalUser.get();

        // Find role by name
        Optional<Role> optionalRole = roleRepository.findByName(roleName);
        if (!optionalRole.isPresent()) {
            throw new RoleNotFoundException("Role with name " + roleName + " not found");
        }
        Role role = optionalRole.get();

        // Check if user has the role
        Set<Role> userRoles = user.getRoles();
        for (Role r : userRoles) {
            if (r.getId().equals(role.getId())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAllByRoleName(String roleName) {
        // Find role by name
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName(roleName)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RoleNotFoundException("Role with name " + roleName + " not found"));

        // Find all users with the specified role
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        for (User user : userRepository.findAll()) {
            if (user.getRoles().contains(role)) {
                users.add(user);
            }
        }
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(String roleName, String permission) {
        // Find role by name
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName(roleName)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RoleNotFoundException("Role with name " + roleName + " not found"));

        // Check if the role has the specified permission
        for (Permission perm : role.getPermissions()) {
            if (perm.name().equals(permission)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canAccessResource(String roleName, String resource) {
        // Find role by name
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName(roleName)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RoleNotFoundException("Role with name " + roleName + " not found"));

        // Check if role has the required permission
        for (Permission permission : Permission.values()) {
            if (permission.name().equals(resource) && role.getPermissions().contains(permission)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAllByNoRoles() {
        List<User> usersWithNoRoles = new ArrayList<>();

        for (User user : userRepository.findAll()) {
            if (user.getRoles().isEmpty()) {
                usersWithNoRoles.add(user);
            }
        }

        return usersWithNoRoles;
    }

}
```

and i have this main application class

```
@ComponentScan("com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios")
@EntityScan("com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.repository")
@SpringBootApplication
public class GestionUsuariosApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GestionUsuariosApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I do not understand what is happening because i dont know why i get these errors if the dependencies are correct, I do not understand this dependency error with Role if it has been configured and injected correctly

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You'd better paste your imports on class `Role`.

Comment: A similar issue might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664064/spring-boot-not-a-managed-type

Comment: im getting this error always 
Field roleRepository in com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.serviceimpl.RoleServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.repository.RoleRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.repository.RoleRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: You should check the source exception, something like `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.entity.Role`

Comment: try this on main class:

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios}")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.entity}")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.repository"})

or

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.*}")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.entity.*}")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.repository.*"})