# Not a managed type entity Skus

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, entity

I have create a simple entity but it is giving me error as  Not a managed type: .entity.Skus

**Entity class**

```
package <path>.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "skus")
public class Skus extends BaseEntity{
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot - Not a managed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664064/spring-boot-not-a-managed-type)

Comment: Looks like `@Table` annotation is missing on your entity..can you try adding that !!

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the import error

```
import javax.persistence.Entity
```

It needs to be replaced with

`import jakarta.persistence.Entity`