# Spring Boot : Not a managed type: class com.example.payroll.Employee

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I receive the error in the question title when trying to compile and run my java program. I'm following this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) provided by the spring docs.

Here is the directory structure:

```
└───payroll
    │   .gitignore
    │   HELP.md
    │   mvnw
    │   mvnw.cmd
    │   pom.xml
    │
    ├───.idea
    │       .gitignore
    │       compiler.xml
    │       encodings.xml
    │       jarRepositories.xml
    │       misc.xml
    │       uiDesigner.xml
    │       workspace.xml
    │
    ├───.mvn
    │   └───wrapper
    │           maven-wrapper.jar
    │           maven-wrapper.properties
    │
    ├───src
    │   ├───main
    │   │   ├───java
    │   │   │   └───com
    │   │   │       └───example
    │   │   │           └───payroll
    │   │   │                   Employee.java
    │   │   │                   EmployeeRepository.java
    │   │   │                   LoadDatabase.java
    │   │   │                   PayrollApplication.java
    │   │   │
    │   │   └───resources
    │   │       │   application.properties
    │   │       │
    │   │       ├───static
    │   │       └───templates
    │   └───test
    │       └───java
    │           └───com
    │               └───example
    │                   └───payroll
    │                           PayrollApplicationTests.java
    │
    └───target
        ├───classes
        │   │   application.properties
        │   │
        │   └───com
        │       └───example
        │           └───payroll
        │                   Employee.class
        │                   EmployeeRepository.class
        │                   LoadDatabase.class
        │                   PayrollApplication.class
        │
        ├───generated-sources
        │   └───annotations
        ├───generated-test-sources
        │   └───test-annotations
        └───test-classes
            └───com
                └───example
                    └───payroll
                            PayrollApplicationTests.class
```

Employee.java :

```
package com.example.payroll;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
class Employee {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    Employee() {}

    Employee(String name, String role) {

        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Employee))
            return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, employee.id) && Objects.equals(this.name, employee.name)
                && Objects.equals(this.role, employee.role);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.id, this.name, this.role);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "id=" + this.id + ", name='" + this.name + '\'' + ", role='" + this.role + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

EmployeeRepository.java :

```
package com.example.payroll;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

LoadDatabase.java :

```
package com.example.payroll;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
class LoadDatabase {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadDatabase.class);

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(EmployeeRepository repository) {

        return args -> {
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Bilbo Baggins", "burglar")));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Frodo Baggins", "thief")));
        };
    }
}
```

PayrollApplication.java :

```
package com.example.payroll;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
@SpringBootApplication
public class PayrollApplication {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PayrollApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And here's the pom.xml file just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>payroll</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>payroll</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've also tried changing the version for the javax.persistence to 2.2 but I keep receiving the same error. Also tried using Entityscan as well... that didn't seem to fix the error either.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot - Not a managed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664064/spring-boot-not-a-managed-type)

Comment: Spring Boot 3.X uses jakarta namespace instead javax. ... so remove the javax.persistence and use `jakarta.persistence` instead

Comment: @TheNytangel unfortunately no, also if add the lines given by the answer to that post it says that 'Redundant declaration: @ SpringBootApplication already applies given '@ ComponentScan'. Even I remove componentscan nothing changes...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you! I used to receive 30 errors and now it's 16... Though it seems that the previous issue ("Not a managed type: class com.example.payroll.Employee") has not been resolved.