# I am currently practicing Spring Boot with Mysql database and after running application getting this error for employeeRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, database-connectivity

**BootjpaexampleApplication.java**

```
package com.jpa.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.jpa.test.dao.EmployeeRepository;
import com.jpa.test.entities.EmployeeDetails;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BootjpaexampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(BootjpaexampleApplication.class, args);
        
        EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = context.getBean(EmployeeRepository.class);
        
        EmployeeDetails empDetails = new EmployeeDetails();
        
        empDetails.setEmpName("Jatin Bundel");
        empDetails.setEmpDepartment("Software Developer");
        empDetails.setEmpSalary(420000);
        
        EmployeeDetails empDetails1 = employeeRepository.save(empDetails);
        
        System.out.println(empDetails1);
    }

}
```

**EmployeeDetails.java**

```
package com.jpa.test.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class EmployeeDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    private String empName;
    
    private String empDepartment;
    
    private double empSalary;

    public EmployeeDetails(int id, String empName, String empDepartment, double empSalary) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.empName = empName;
        this.empDepartment = empDepartment;
        this.empSalary = empSalary;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmpDepartment() {
        return empDepartment;
    }

    public void setEmpDepartment(String empDepartment) {
        this.empDepartment = empDepartment;
    }

    public double getEmpSalary() {
        return empSalary;
    }

    public void setEmpSalary(double empSalary) {
        this.empSalary = empSalary;
    }

    public EmployeeDetails() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmployeeDetails [id=" + id + ", empName=" + empName + ", empDepartment=" + empDepartment
                + ", empSalary=" + empSalary + "]";
    }
}
```

**EmployeeRepository.java**

```
package com.jpa.test.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.jpa.test.entities.EmployeeDetails;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<EmployeeDetails, Integer> {

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.name=test
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I already tried to add all files in the main package but does not solved this error.

I did changed my application properties. And tried every single combination but it refuses to work.

## Error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-10-01T17:56:08.903+05:30 ERROR 3248 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.jpa.test.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.jpa.test.EmployeeDetails
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.jpa.test.BootjpaexampleApplication.main(BootjpaexampleApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.jpa.test.EmployeeDetails
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot - Not a managed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664064/spring-boot-not-a-managed-type)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks my problem is resolved what I do is just replace 
```import javax.persistence``` To ```import jakarta.persistence```

Comment: Now data is not Entering in the Database

Comment: Then you've got other, new problems.