# How do I wire a (subclass/subinterface of a) JpaRepository via Xml configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa, java-11

How do I wire a (subclass/subinterface) of JpaRepository via Xml configuration?

So I have an "implementation" of JpaRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface MyDepartmentJpaRepo extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {

   /* "lookup strategy".  see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods */
    Optional<Department> findDepartmentByDepartmentNameEquals(String departmentName);

    Collection<Department> findByCreateOffsetDateTimeBefore(OffsetDateTime zdt);

}
```

and the entity

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DepartmentTable")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DepartmentKey", unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long departmentKey;

    @Column(name = "DepartmentName", unique = true)
    private String departmentName;

    @Column(name = "CreateOffsetDateTime", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" )
    private OffsetDateTime createOffsetDateTime;

    public long getDepartmentKey() {
        return departmentKey;
    }

    public void setDepartmentKey(long departmentKey) {
        this.departmentKey = departmentKey;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getCreateOffsetDateTime() {
        return createOffsetDateTime;
    }

    public void setCreateOffsetDateTime(OffsetDateTime createOffsetDateTime) {
        this.createOffsetDateTime = createOffsetDateTime;
    }
}
```

and a class where I need to inject the MyDepartmentJpaRepo

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class DepartmentManager implements IDepartmentManager {

    private final Logger logger;
    private final MyDepartmentJpaRepo deptRepo;

    /* The Inject annotation marks which constructor to use for IoC when there are multiple constructors */
    @Inject
    public DepartmentManager(MyDepartmentJpaRepo deptRepo) {
        this(LoggerFactory.getLogger(DepartmentManager.class), deptRepo);
    }

    public DepartmentManager(Logger lgr, MyDepartmentJpaRepo deptRepo) {
        if (null == lgr) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Logger is null");
        }

        if (null == deptRepo) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("IDepartmentDomainData is null");
        }

        this.logger = lgr;
        this.deptRepo = deptRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Department> getAll() {
        List<Department> returnItems = this.deptRepo.findAll();
        return returnItems;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Department> getSingle(long key) {
        Optional<Department> returnItem = this.deptRepo.findById(key);
        return  returnItem;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Department> getSingleByName(String deptName) {
        Optional<Department> returnItem = this.deptRepo.findDepartmentByDepartmentNameEquals(deptName);
        return  returnItem;
    }

    public Collection<Department> getDepartmentsOlderThanDate(OffsetDateTime zdt)
    {
        Collection<Department> returnItems = this.deptRepo.findByCreateOffsetDateTimeBefore(zdt);
        return returnItems;
    }

    @Override
    public Department save(Department item) {
        Department returnItem = this.deptRepo.save(item);
        return  returnItem;
    }
}
```

and the interface of the "manager" for completeness.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface IDepartmentManager {

    Collection<Department> getAll();

    Optional<Department> getSingle(long key);

    Optional<Department> getSingleByName(String deptName);

    Department save(Department item);

    Collection<Department> getDepartmentsOlderThanDate(OffsetDateTime zdt);
}
```

The issue is in the applicationcontext.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <import resource="jpaSetup.di.xml"/>

    <bean id="MyDepartmentJpaRepoBean" class="com.mycompany.blah.blah.blah.MyDepartmentJpaRepo">
    </bean>

    <bean id="IDepartmentManagerBean" class="com.mycompany.blah.blah.blah.DepartmentManager">
        <constructor-arg ref="MyDepartmentJpaRepoBean"/>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

So..the spring-boot-data makes one define the (sub-interfaced JpaRepository) AS AN INTERFACE

```
interface MyDepartmentJpaRepo extends JpaRepository<Department, Long>
```

So when you try to xml-define the IoC/DI..you get "**interface not allowed for non-abtract beans**".

This looks like a catch-22 ...... :(

The magic question:

**How does one use xml-config for IoC/DI...................and take advantage of a sub-interfaced JpaRepository ????**

APPEND:

If I add in "jpa:repositories", then I don't have a constructor-arg for the "manager".

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

```
<import resource="jpaSetup.di.xml"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.blah.blah.blah" />
```

-->
-->

```
<bean id="IDepartmentManagerBean" class="com.mycompany.organizationdemo.businesslayer.managers.DepartmentManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="NotDoesNotExistMyDepartmentJpaRepoBean"/> <!-- DOES NOT WORK -->
</bean>
```

..................

other files below for completeness.

jpaSetup.di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <beans>

        <bean id="myLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBeanBean"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.blah.blah.blah.entities"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="showSql" value="${spring.jpa.show-sql}"/>
                    <property name="generateDdl" value="${spring.jpa.generate-ddl}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <!-- See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088112/how-to-auto-detect-entities-in-jpa-2-0/16088340#16088340 -->
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="url" value="${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}"/>
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME}"/>
        </bean>


        <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBeanBean"/>
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

        <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class=
                "org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    </beans>

</beans>
```

and application.yml

```
spring:
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  datasource:
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    driverClassName: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the reference documenation : [XML Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring)

Following configuration works based on the understanding that

> Each bean is registered under a bean name that is derived from the
>   interface name, so an interface of UserRepository would be registered
>   under userRepository.

So the bean name for interface

```
public interface MyDepartmentJpaRepo extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {
..
}
```

would be as follows : `myDepartmentJpaRepo`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
     https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

   <jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.organizationdemo.businesslayer.repository"/>

    <bean id="IDepartmentManagerBean" class="com.mycompany.organizationdemo.businesslayer.managers.DepartmentManager">
        <constructor-arg ref="myDepartmentJpaRepo"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

For verification , I autowired and used the DepartmentManager instance as follows

```
@Autowired
IDepartmentManager manager;
```

Spring boot version : 2.2.6

Also the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances) mentions the following

> One way to do so is by using the Spring namespace that is shipped with
>   each Spring Data module that supports the repository mechanism,
>   although we generally recommend using Java configuration.

Note: the package names are modified to match the question , please modify as required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow.  That simple.  lower case first letter.  I did know about that spring-di voodoo before.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation references.  And not just the simple answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is far more simple and better than this answer.  (Answer from "R.G.").  However, I did find a ugly workaround for future readers.

DO NOT PREFER THIS ANSWER OVER the one from R.G. !

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Component
public class DepartmentJpaRepositoryFactory {

    @Inject
    private MyDepartmentJpaRepo autoinjectedDepartmentJpaRepositoryWorkaround;

    /* this is a workaround for using explicit xml IOC with spring-data.
    * because it is "interface MyDepartmentJpaRepo" (not a class), you cannot do traditional xml IoC definitions :(
    * this is a workaround.  this factory should NEVER be used by the code base, only by spring-di  */
    public MyDepartmentJpaRepo getInstanceDepartmentJpaRepository() {
        return this.autoinjectedDepartmentJpaRepositoryWorkaround;
    }
}
```

and then applicationcontext.xml

```
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.blah.blah.blah.jpa.repositories" />

<bean id="DepartmentManagerBean" class="com.blah.blah.blah.managers.DepartmentManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="DepartmentJpaRepositoryViaFactoryMethodBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="DepartmentJpaRepositoryServiceLocatorBean" class="com.blah.blah.blah.jpa.factories.DepartmentJpaRepositoryFactory">
    <!-- inject any dependencies required by this locator bean -->
</bean>

<bean id="DepartmentJpaRepositoryViaFactoryMethodBean"
      factory-bean="DepartmentJpaRepositoryServiceLocatorBean"
      factory-method="getInstanceDepartmentJpaRepository"/>
```

the above is an ugly and nasty workaround using

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method

"Instantiation by Using an Instance Factory Method"