# Required entities listing in persistence.xml on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jersey, guice, datanucleus

I'm developing an application that uses GAE, Guice, JPA 2.0 and Jersey. I want to get rid of adding each entity class as a `<class>` element in my persistence.xml.

Answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780341/do-i-need-class-elements-in-persistence-xml) talk only about Hibernate, but AFAIK only supported JPA provider for Google App Engine is DataNucleus.

My project structure (my only entity right now is TestObject.java; target directory is generated via Maven):

```
├── README.md
├── datanucleus.log
├── nb-configuration.xml
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── cz
│       │       └── cvut
│       │           └── oi
│       │               └── wa2
│       │                   ├── ioc
│       │                   │   ├── Configuration.java
│       │                   │   └── ServletListener.java
│       │                   └── rest
│       │                       ├── JSONService.java
│       │                       └── TestObject.java
│       ├── resources
│       │   └── META-INF
│       │       └── persistence.xml
│       └── webapp
│           └── WEB-INF
│               ├── appengine-web.xml
│               └── web.xml
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   ├── META-INF
    │   │   └── persistence.xml
    │   └── cz
    │       └── cvut
    │           └── oi
    │               └── wa2
    │                   ├── ioc
    │                   └── rest
    ├── generated-sources
    │   └── annotations
    ├── maven-archiver
    │   └── pom.properties
    ├── rss-reader-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT
    │   ├── META-INF
    │   └── WEB-INF
    │       ├── appengine-generated
    │       │   └── local_db.bin
    │       ├── appengine-web.xml
    │       ├── classes
    │       │   └── META-INF
    │       │       └── persistence.xml
    │       ├── lib
    │       │   ├── activation-1.1.jar
    │       │   ├── aopalliance-1.0.jar
    │       │   ├── appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar
    │       │   ├── asm-3.1.jar
    │       │   ├── datanucleus-api-jpa-3.0.11.jar
    │       │   ├── datanucleus-appengine-2.0.1.jar
    │       │   ├── datanucleus-core-3.0.11.jar
    │       │   ├── geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.1.jar
    │       │   ├── guice-3.0.jar
    │       │   ├── guice-persist-3.0.jar
    │       │   ├── guice-servlet-3.0.jar
    │       │   ├── jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
    │       │   ├── jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
    │       │   ├── jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
    │       │   ├── jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
    │       │   ├── javax.inject-1.jar
    │       │   ├── jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
    │       │   ├── jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
    │       │   ├── jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
    │       │   ├── jersey-core-1.17.1.jar
    │       │   ├── jersey-guice-1.17.1.jar
    │       │   ├── jersey-json-1.17.1.jar
    │       │   ├── jersey-server-1.17.1.jar
    │       │   ├── jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar
    │       │   ├── jettison-1.1.jar
    │       │   ├── jta-1.1.jar
    │       │   ├── rss-reader-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │       │   └── stax-api-1.0-2.jar
    │       └── web.xml
    ├── rss-reader-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
    └── surefire
```

Is my requirement possible with this devstack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataNucleus core certainly [supports classpath scanning](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jpa/persistence_unit.html) when **exclude-unlisted-classes** is not present when used with JavaEE or JavaSE. The log (DEBUG level) would show what is being discovered.

Comment: I am not sure what am I supposed to do. I updated the question with my project structure.

Comment: Perhaps think about your question. You asked does DataNucleus support CLASSPATH scanning so you don't need to put class entries in persistence.xml. I answered that, and pointed to the log as the way of seeing what is happening. If you have some "problem" then raise a question based around that problem.

Comment: I don't know how to edit or even print my CLASSPATH with App Engine/Maven and what "DataNucleus will search for annotated classes starting at the root of the persistence-unit (the root directory in the CLASSPATH that contains the "META-INF/persistence.xml" file)" exactly means.

Comment: The CLASSPATH is accessed via ClassLoaders, and things in the CLASSPATH are accessible via ClassLoader.getResources; this is what DataNucleus uses. How GAE puts things in the CLASSPATH is not something I can answer since it's not something I use, and DataNucleus core uses the CLASSPATH that is provided. System.getProperty("java.class.path") is the CLASSPATH which can easily be used for diagnostics