# Spring integration test- database schema generation from another project

Tags: integration-testing, embedded-database, spring-test

This is my setup for integration testing with spring and embedded database H2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/globalParams.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/customersGroupView.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/recentIntegrationsTableAndTrigger.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/insertIntegrationDate.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/toCharRoutine.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
</beans>
```

Abstract parent of integration tests

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = [
    "classpath:com/dhl/dcc/dcc-core.xml",
    "classpath:com/dhl/dcc/test-security.xml",
    "classpath:com/dhl/dcc/dcc-audit.xml",
    "classpath:com/dhl/dcc/test-dataSource.xml",
    "classpath:com/dhl/dcc/test-beans.xml",
    "classpath:com/dhl/dcc/dcc-forms.xml"
])
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTestCase extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
```

and in core cofiguration of entity manager factory

```
<property name="generateDdl" value="${dcc.orm.generateDdl:false}"/>
```

property dcc.orm.generateDdl is set to true in properties.

It worked well (database schema was generated from classes annotated @Entity) but now i separated domain model into its own project and added this project as dependency in Maven. After that my integration tests starting to fail because of missing db schema. How do i configure where should embedded database look for a domain model? Thanks.

edit: entity factory configuration

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="DCC"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="${dcc.orm.generateDdl:false}"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="${dcc.orm.showSql:false}"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${dcc.orm.dialect}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Does your jar contain this "classpath:sql/globalParams.sql"? Usually test resources are not packaged into the jar, but *-test.jar. So if the sql files are under test directory, package your test jar and add it to your target project as well.

Comment: The scripts are not a problem. They are beeing executed. Problem is that DB schema in embedded database is not created from the JPA entities.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Could you post spring xml contains your entityManagerFactory?

Comment: Have you tried adding"<property name="packagesToScan" value="package in your jar" />" to your entityManagerFactory?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried specify jar file in *persistence.xml*? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1780362/204950

Or try to set *exclude-unlisted-classes* to false, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1780437/204950

Comment: Seting excluding unlisted classes to false or true does not have any result. Copying jar to dependecy folder in target works, but it does not work for tests. Only thing that helps is listing all entity classes in using <class> tag in persistence.xml, but i dont like this approach.