# Why am I forced to list entity classes in persistence.xml?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

TomEE 1.6  JPA 2.0  Hibernate 2.4.8  MySQL.

`exclude-unlisted-classes` set to false should not force me to list entities.

Without `<class>com.acme.Person</class>`, I get 'Unknown entity com.acme.Person'. Anyone knows why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
     version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.acme.Person</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        ...

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Do I need <class> elements in persistence.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780341/do-i-need-class-elements-in-persistence-xml).

Comment: Removed class entry. Added `<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>`. No luck.