# Hibernate 4.3.11 - Envers fails with ZonedDateTime field

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I try use @Audited in Domain class, but Domain have a ZonedDateTime fields and receive error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at br.com.engdb.geotec.GeotecApp.main(GeotecApp.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: BasicType adapter for AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime,Date>, at table: plan_aud, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(date_limit)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildEntityBasedAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor106.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

I try use @Converter for ZonedDateTime field to DateTime, but doesn´t works.
Somebody help me ?
Same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358912/hibernate-envers-fails-with-converter-and-attributeconverter-jpa-2-1/42297007#42297007)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `ZoneDateTime` is a Java 8 type and therefore requires the inclusion of a special artifact called `hibernate-java8` in order to gain access to that type.  This artifact was not published until Hibernate 5.0, so using Hibernate 4.3 isn't compliant if you want to use java 8 types without writing the type implementation yourself.

From Hibernate 5.2 onward, Java 8 is the baseline; ergo, the types in `hibernate-java8` were merged into `hibernate-core` and the `hibernate-java8` artifact made obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by updating the version of hibernate and jackson to a newer one.

I use SqlServer in this case, so I needed to change the dialect.

Comment: See my answer for a more conclusive and clear reason why a new hibernate version is necessary to use `ZoneDateTime` in any Hibernate entity, not just Envers.