# JPA2: ElementCollection of Enum combined with AttributeConverter

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to combine two concepts:

- Store Enums, which are in a one-to-many relationship of an entity (using `@ElementCollection`, `@CollectionTable`)
- Persist the Enums not by String or Ordinal, but by a unique ID (using `@AttributeConverter`)

Individually they should to work fine (judging by the docs), but when I combine them, I get errors during build.

Here's the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "push_tokens")
public class PushTokenDAO implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idx;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = NotificationType.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Convert(converter = NotificationTypeConverter.class)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "notificationtypes_of_tokens",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_tokenIdx")
    )
    @Column(name = "notificationType")
    private List<NotificationType> notificationTypes;

    /* ... */

}
```

This is the Enum:

```
public enum NotificationType {
    NEW_TRANSFER(10),
    DELIVERY_REPORT(20),
    UPLOAD_CONFIRMATION(30),
    EXPIRY_WARNING(40);

    private final int code;

    NotificationType(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public static NotificationType parse(int code) {
        for (NotificationType t : NotificationType.values()) {
            if (t.code == code) {
                return t;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such NotificationType");
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

The converter:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class NotificationTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<NotificationType, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(NotificationType x) {
        return x.getCode();
    }

    @Override
    public NotificationType convertToEntityAttribute(Integer y) {
        return NotificationType.parse(y);
    }

}
```

The collection-table `notificationtypes_of_tokens` has just the two numeric columns in it:

```
CREATE TABLE `notificationtypes_of_tokens` (
  `fk_tokenIdx` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `notificationType` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fk_tokenIdx`,`notificationType`),
  KEY `fk_tokenIdx` (`fk_tokenIdx`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The problem occurs during EclipseLink's static weaving, which is part of the build process:

```
Failed to execute goal de.empulse.eclipselink:staticweave-maven-plugin:1.0.0:weave (default) 
on project skp-server: Execution default of goal de.empulse.eclipselink:staticweave-maven-plugin:1.0.0:weave 
failed: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [skp-server-PU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7351] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The converter class [com.skalio.skaliopush.db.NotificationTypeConverter] 
    specified on the mapping attribute [notificationTypes] from the class 
    [com.skalio.skaliopush.db.entity.PushTokenDAO] was not found. Please ensure the converter 
    class name is correct and exists with the persistence unit definition.
```

If I don't specifically reference the converter in the entity (leave out `@Convert`), the conversion is not done; the Enum is mapped to its ordinal. This is not what I want.

FYI: The code runs on a Java SE VM, not an application server or something. I have to specify each entity class in `persistence.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has nothing to do with `@ElementCollection`, Enums or the combination with an `@AttributeConverter`.

Instead, the answer lies in the question [what has to be specified in persistence.xml when running on Java SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1780437/295962). The error message was hinting in that way as well ('converter not found...').

After specifying the converter class in `persistence.xml`, weaving works fine, the code builds, and it runs as expected. In summary: **Combining `@ElementCollection`, Enum and `@AttributeConverter` works just fine, as per the code above.**