# Mapping all the classes in hibernate.cfg.xml with just one line?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-mapping

I'm a bit lazy and i'm trying to find a single liner to map all my classes in my `hibernate.cfg.config`. (I'm using annotations not an xml file)

What i've tried to do :

```
<mapping class="my_group.my_artifact.*"></mapping>
```

Can this be acheived using one line of code?
I've looked to other answers on SO but didn't find a lazy way that fits me, and I'm new to SO to I'll appreciate any helpful comment.

Comment: Maybe you give more specific examples why they "dont fit" you. How are we supposed to know what you have read so far and "rejected" when you don't tell us?

Comment: Ah sorry for that, but what i meant by "don't fit" is just that i'm looking for a one-line code to do the job, "out of the box". Otherwise i found other ways to do it, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413190/hibernate-mapping-package) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it using Hibernate only.

You can use Spring with `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean` (package  `hibernate5` for Hibernate 5, change it if need) or additional libraries as described here:

[Hibernate config not list all Entities in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36976074/3405171)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that out! My company isn't using spring or anything like that for the moment so i'll have to do it manually ! cheers