# Hibernate throwing a QuerySyntaxException with correct class name given

Tags: java, hibernate, resteasy

1. I have a `Product` class;

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Product {
       .
       .
       public Product() { }
       .
       .
   }
   ```
2. A generic DAO;

   ```
   public class GenericDao<T> {

       private Class<T> type;

       @Inject
       protected EntityManager entityManager;

       public GenericDao() { }


       public List<T> list() {
           return entityManager.createQuery("FROM " + type.getSimpleName(), type).getResultList();
       }
   }
   ```
3. A Product DAO class;

   `public class ProductDao extends BaseDao<Product> { }`
4. A product JAX-RS service;

   ```
   @Path("/product")
   public class ProductService {

       @Inject
       private ProductDao productDao;

       @GET
       @Path("/getProducts")
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       public List<Product> getProducts() {
           List<Product> response = productDao.list();
           return response;
       }
   }
   ```

   When I run the app and make a call to the endpoint I get a nice QuerySyntaxException;

   ```
   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Product is not mapped [FROM Product]
   ```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="mainconfig">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
       <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/awsapp" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${conf.jdbc.user}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${conf.jdbc.password}" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: What does your `persistence.xml` look like?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have included the `persistence.xml` config

Comment: @Azola Where have you declared that class Product contains a mapping? I mean, in one of your configuration files, you must indicate that Product (or its package) got to be managed by the persistence manager.

Comment: You can see an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780341/do-i-need-class-elements-in-persistence-xml

Comment: Your `persistence.xml` is invalid. It doesn't have the opening `properties` tag.

Comment: Can you put " <class>yourpackage.path.Product</class>" to under the "persistence-unit" in persistence.xml ?

Comment: I ran into something similar when setting-up a second `persistence.xml` in the test resources to be used in the unit tests. It turned-out something about the order of classloading prevented it from finding the classes and I had to list them all as @GltknBtn suggested. Try doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid conflicts, specify your Class and entity manager in implementation classes. Example :

```
public abstract class GenericDao<T> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public GenericDao(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public T getById(Long key) {
        return getEntityManager().find(clazz, key);
    }
    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();
}
```

Then your implementation class :

```
public class ProductDao extends BaseDao<Product> { 
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public ProductDao(){
        super(Product.class);
    }

        /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

Comment: An abstract method needs to be in an abstract class, but this worked for me

Comment: Indeed :) The method should be abstract anyway. I would even suggest having a generic interface and a common abstract implementation. Your concrete class would then extend this common abstract implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put full name instead of simpleClassName.

as below

> "FROM " + type.getName()

Comment: No, this returns the full class name with the package

Comment: Is not not working? Or you getting the same exception using it?

Comment: I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException