# How to setup Hibernate JPA in Spring-Boot project without Spring Data?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-jpa

I am quite new to Spring and have a task to create a multi-module project that needs to use Hibernate JPA and Spring-Boot (Spring Data JPA is not allowed for this project).

I am using the PostgreSQL database and `org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final`.

I added hibernate JPA and on its own, it works but I don't know how to configure it to work in my spring-boot project. And most examples use spring-data-jpa.

I tried `@PersitenceContect` annotation for my EntityManager but that doesn't work.

I also tried following this: https://allaroundjava.com/hibernate-jpa-spring-tutorial/
But maybe because of different databases or maybe smth else I couldn't get it to work.

I **solved** this by following JPA configuration described in this question: [Spring Boot + Hibernate JPA configuration to use EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963183/spring-boot-hibernate-jpa-configuration-to-use-entitymanager?rq=1&fbclid=IwAR0SuAGM_wii22Gp_7yt7Y3ODNgb8JvVFPMKKF3DvIKYxqGmqHjLJLshV5Y)

Comment: Just add hibernate, entities and provide datasource configuration.

Comment: What is being done in that question isn't needed you can ditch all that. What I stated in the comment is all you need, nothing more nothing less.

Answer (score -1):

A great tutorial with an example (with postgres) is the following one : https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-postgresql-example/

It shows how to structure your file structure (etc) which is nice.

Comment: linked tutorial uses Spring Data, hence doesn't answer the question